# Why are three intevals necessary for writing to memory in a MIPS 32 bit architecture?

Tags: memory, architecture, mips, hardware, clock

[image: Shows how the three intervals line up with clock cycles]

Working with a MIPS 32 bit architecture, I'm not sure what the three intervals are for. I am guessing the first has to do with fetching something from memory, but I really don't know. If anyone could walk me through the process that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I solved it, the intervals are mostly for setup and hold times as shown below.

[image: Intervals for memory writes]